# Different Pages in WordPress having same Header and footer

Tags: wordpress, header, footer

Is it possible to have the same **header and footer** for **different pages** in WordPress without plugins? If yes, how ??

Comment: This is exactly how WP works at the moment. Can you explain a bit more about what you're experiencing, maybe giving details of what theme you're using, a link to your site?

Comment: Wordpress already have function get_footer() and  get_footer() that is used in almost all theme to achieve same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

use get_header(); & get_footer(); on custom template.

## first make the template like test.php on theme root

then paste this

```
        <?php
  /**
  * Template Name: Custom Post List
  */
  get_header(); ?>

  <div id="main-content" class="main-content">

  <?php
  if ( is_front_page() && twentyfourteen_has_featured_posts() ) {
    // Include the featured content template.
    get_template_part( 'featured-content' );
  }
 ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

        <h1>Hello There</h1>

    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
  </div><!-- #main-content -->

   <?php
   get_sidebar();
   get_footer();
```

## then create page in admin and  select the template

Comment: So where do i need to put this code in my page "http://app.mixorg.com/travel_website/wp-admin/post.php?post=400&action=edit " this is the page where i want to have header and footer same like the home page, i.e. "http://app.mixorg.com/travel_website/"

Comment: first create a template and then assign that template into page. with get_header(); and get_footer();